# Como limpio canva que se actualiza cada segundo - python

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, refresh

es la primera vez que toco python. y estoy teniendo un problema visual con la ventana. se ve asi cada que actualiza:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

es un "reloj" que rota, pero se queda pegado visualmente el camino. ya intente con el `canvas.delete('all')` pero no me sirve, y creo que es por lo que se "instancia" un nuevo canva cada segundo

y este es el codigo:

```
import tkinter as tk
from time import strftime

def actualizar_reloj():
    global angulo_rotacion
    tiempo_actual = strftime('%S')
    # canvas.delete("etiqueta_rotativa")
    canvas.delete('all') 
    angulo_rotacion = (angulo_rotacion + 2) % 360
    print(angulo_rotacion)
    for i in range(3):
        tiempo_actual += "   " + tiempo_actual
    canvas.create_text(250, 250, text=tiempo_actual, angle=angulo_rotacion*-1, tags="etiqueta_rotativa", anchor=tk.NW)
    ventana.after(1000, actualizar_reloj)

# Configuracion de ventana
ventana = tk.Tk()
ventana.title("Ola k ase")
ancho_pantalla = ventana.winfo_screenwidth()
alto_pantalla = ventana.winfo_screenheight()
ancho_ventana = 500
alto_ventana = 500
x = (ancho_pantalla - ancho_ventana) // 2
y = (alto_pantalla - alto_ventana) // 2
ventana.geometry(f'{ancho_ventana}x{alto_ventana}+{x}+{y}')

# creacion de Canva
canvas = tk.Canvas(ventana, width=ancho_ventana, height=alto_ventana, bg='white')
canvas.pack()

# variables
angulo_rotacion = -362

actualizar_reloj()
ventana.mainloop()
```

Comment: Debería funcionar, no estas creando un canvas cada segundo, limpias el canvas (eliminas todos sus items) y agregas un item nuevo cada segundo. He intentado reproducir el problema, pero en mi caso (Linux- Mutter (Wayland)) funciona perfectamente... Podrías actualizar el item en vez de eliminarlo, pero no creo que solucione el problema. No es solo que queden trazas de los items anteriores, es que el actual tampoco se dibuja bien...

Comment: Exacto, no se si sea el Windows 11 que me este generando ese fallo, intentare correrlo en un Win10 a ver. o puede que tenga alguna configuracion grafica desmarcada en el SO

Comment: Te dejo una versión actualizando el ítem por si quieres probarla a ver si se produce el mismo problema o no: https://pastebin.com/JT2ZfBnA. Como comento arriba no creo que sea este el problema, pero...

Comment: Dale muchas gracias, siguio fallando asi que probare en otro S.O mañana... apenas lo resuelva aviso por aqui

Comment: Creo que es algo de Windows 11. Para mi sorpresa, pude reproducir el fallo copiando el código...

Answer (score 0):

la función canvas.delete("all") borra absolutamente todo lo que hay en el lienzo. Ahora si lo quieres hacer un poco específico solo escribe el nombre del elemento que quieres borrar que se puede hacer o con tags o con el igual.`import tkinter as tk import time ventana = tk.Tk() canvas = tk.Canvas(ventana, height="500", width="600", background="white") canvas.pack() canvas.create_line(50,60,100,120) canvas.delete("all")`

Comment: está un poco desastroso pero bueno soy nuevo dale bien y confirma para que me suba el prestigio

Comment: perdon por la respuesta es que no leí todo

Comment: A lo mejor si el código lo copias de aquí te va nunca se sabe

Comment: nada si me quieren tirar la pregunta por pedir votos haganlo